# Using numpy.fromregex on a text file with colon separated digits

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
# sparse.txt
1 1:1 2:1 3:1
0 1:1 4:1
1 12:1 13:1 14:1
```

I want to create a matrix without colons which looks like this:

```
# sparse2.txt
1 1 1 2 1 3 1
0 1 1 4 1
1 2 1 3 1 4 1
```

I used online python regex to find the regex pattern to read the rows of the file.
https://pythex.org/

I used the pattern:

```
pat = [0-1]\s+([0-9]:1\s*)+
```

Which satisfies the regex in online regexer, but, when I used it in np.fromregex
it does not work.

```
import numpy as np
pat = r'[0-1]\s+([0-9]:1\s*)+'

data = np.fromregex('sparse.txt', pat, dtype='str')
print("data = {}".format(data))
```

How can we fix the error?

Comment: Try [`r'([0-1])\s+([0-9]):(1)\s+([0-9]):(1)(?:\s+([0-9]):(1))?'`](https://regex101.com/r/7NWLR9/2)

Comment: Is there a bunch of other data that you don't want to match? Why not just replace `:` with a space?

Comment: `fromregex` just does a `re.findall(pat, f.read())`, and then tries to make an array from the resulting list of tuples.  Your original line splits is easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 0):

### What's wrong

**`[0-1]\s+([0-9]:1\s*)+`**

- This will match the **entire line** instead of the **each numerical number** which you want.
  [image]

### How to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
pat = r'^\d|[^0-9\:\n][\d]?'

data = np.fromregex('sparse.txt', pat, [('num', np.int64)])
print("data = {}".format(data))
```

### Result

[image]

### Suggestions

- Use [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com) to help you compose the regex pattern
- `numpy.fromregex` official reference [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html)

Comment: This gives 1D array, how can we print it like sparse2.txt, as shown in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

With @Wiktor's pattern

```
In [58]: pat1 = r'([0-1])\s+([0-9]):(1)\s+([0-9]):(1)(?:\s+([0-9]):(1))?'
In [59]: np.fromregex('stack47266965.txt', pat1, dtype='str')
Out[59]: 
array([['1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '1'],
       ['0', '1', '1', '4', '1', '', ''],
       ['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '4', '1']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

This is a 2d array of dtype string (unicode here); note the padding for the short 2nd line.  That's produced by the `?:` portion of the pattern.

`fromregex` does a `re.findall` and casts that list of tuples into an array:

```
In [60]: re.findall(pat1, open('stack47266965.txt').read())
Out[60]: 
[('1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '1'),
 ('0', '1', '1', '4', '1', '', ''),
 ('1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '4', '1')]
```

Note that the `fromregex` documentation stresses that it returns a `structured array`.  That list of tuples can be the correct input to a `np.array(seq, dtype=dt)`, where `dt` is a compound dtype.  Each tuple should have the same length, one that matches the `dtype`.

This case shows that it works with a simple dtype like `str`.  But what does this do for you.  You can't convert those strings to numbers, without somehow filtering out the blanks.  And without the blanks the array can not longer be 2d.  That short middle line prevents that.

The text file readers in `numpy` are designed to read the file line by line, parsing each into a row of a 2d array, or a record of a 1d structured array.  Irregular line length is a problem, requiring some sort of fill.

@XetRAFHan's pattern extracts all the numbers you want, but looses the row structure:

```
In [93]: pat2 = r'^\d|[^0-9\:\n][\d]?'
In [94]: re.findall(pat2, open('stack47266965.txt').read())
Out[94]: ['1', ' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 1', ' 4', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4']
```

The kind of split that you did before retains the file structure

[Create dense matrix from sparse matrix efficently (numpy/scipy but NO sklearn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266965/create-dense-matrix-from-sparse-matrix-efficently-numpy-scipy-but-no-sklearn)

```
In [95]: lines = open('stack47266965.txt').readlines()
In [96]: lines
Out[96]: ['1 1:1 2:1 3:1\n', '0 1:1 4:1\n', '1 2:1 3:1 4:1\n']
In [97]: alist = []
In [98]: for line in lines:
    ...:     row = line.split()
    ...:     label = int(row[0])
    ...:     values = [int(a.split(':')[0]) for a in row[1:]]
    ...:     alist.append((label, values))
    ...:     
In [99]: alist
Out[99]: [(1, [1, 2, 3]), (0, [1, 4]), (1, [2, 3, 4])]
```